# How to set default font family for WebView in React Native?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a View that displays title & body. I use a Text element for the title and a WebView for the body(the body is html content).
The problem is: The font in WebView and native Text element are different. How to set font family for WebView to have same result as in the Text element?

Answer (score 0):

Styling of the content of WebView is controlled by CSS, like in regular HTML. So you need to set `font-family` in CSS. If you don't have control over the content (i.e. if it is a remote page you are loading), [you can inject JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript) that sets or modifies the required bits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how to get default font name from system to set to WebView?